# How does ssl connection to DB2 WoC work without a certificate provided explicitly

Tags: ssl, db2

I have a db2 WoC instance that is ssl enabled. Unlike rest of the other db2 warehouses with SSL enabled, I do not need to provide explicit certificate path - db2 driver is able to take care of it. So my connection string looks like:

```
<host>:<port>/db:sslConnection=true;
```

I do not have db2 driver package installed https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2whc?topic=Db2whc-ssl_support which comes equipped with CA cert. I only have a standalone db2jcc driver.

Where exactly the certificate coming from? I looked inside the jar but could not locate it there either

Answer (score 1):

If the Db2 WHoC server certificate is signed by one of the commonly recognised certificate authorities (which is likely to be the case and also is easy to verify), the corresponding CA certificate might be supplied by your operating system or the JVM, from where the driver picks it up.

Comment: that was the case indeed!

Answer (score 0):

[Db2 Warehouse on Cloud / SSL connectivity](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2whc?topic=Db2whc-ssl_support):

> **The CA certificate is part of the Db2 driver package. If your
> application connects with a driver from the Db2 driver package, you do
> not need to download the certificate separately.** You can download the
> Db2 driver package from the web console.
>
> However, if your application has its own driver, you might need to
> download the certificate separately. You can download the certificate
> from the web console.